# Transform Pandas DataFrame with n-level hierarchical index into n-D Numpy array

Tags: python, pandas, multidimensional-array, multi-index

#### Question

Is there a good way to transform a DataFrame with an *n*-level index into an *n*-D Numpy array (a.k.a *n*-tensor)?

---

#### Example

Suppose I set up a DataFrame like

```
from pandas import DataFrame, MultiIndex

index = range(2), range(3)
value = range(2 * 3)
frame = DataFrame(value, columns=['value'],
                  index=MultiIndex.from_product(index)).drop((1, 0))
print frame
```

which outputs

```
     value
0 0      0
  1      1
  2      3
1 1      5
  2      6
```

The index is a 2-level hierarchical index. I can extract a 2-D Numpy array from the data using

```
print frame.unstack().values
```

which outputs

```
[[  0.   1.   2.]
 [ nan   4.   5.]]
```

**How does this generalize to an *n*-level index?**

Playing with `unstack()`, it seems that it can only be used to massage the 2-D shape of the DataFrame, but not to add an axis.

I cannot use e.g. `frame.values.reshape(x, y, z)`, since this would require that the frame contains exactly `x * y * z` rows, which cannot be guaranteed. This is what I tried to demonstrate by `drop()`ing a row in the above example.

Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: The answer to "how does it generalize" is it doesn't.  A pandas DataFrame is fundamentally a two-dimensional object.  As your example shows, it doesn't enforce equal sizes across index "dimensions", so if you try to expand it to more dimensions, there may be gaps.  I think if you want to get an n-D array you may have to make it yourself by iterating over the index levels and creating a separate "slice" of the result array for each.  Pandas just isn't targeted at that sort of structure.

Comment: Thanks @Bren. I managed to address the problem of missing rows and to use `reshape()` (see below). This seems to work on my dataset, although I wouldn't be surprised if there are situations where it chokes.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Edit**. This approach is much more elegant (and two orders of magnitude faster) than the one I gave below.

```
# create an empty array of NaN of the right dimensions
shape = map(len, frame.index.levels)
arr = np.full(shape, np.nan)

# fill it using Numpy's advanced indexing
arr[frame.index.codes] = frame.values.flat
# ...or in Pandas < 0.24.0, use
# arr[frame.index.labels] = frame.values.flat
```

---

**Original solution**. Given a setup similar to above, but in 3-D,

```
from pandas import DataFrame, MultiIndex
from itertools import product

index = range(2), range(2), range(2)
value = range(2 * 2 * 2)
frame = DataFrame(value, columns=['value'],
                  index=MultiIndex.from_product(index)).drop((1, 0, 1))
print(frame)
```

we have

```
       value
0 0 0      0
    1      1
  1 0      2
    1      3
1 0 0      4
  1 0      6
    1      7
```

Now, we proceed using the `reshape()` route, but with some preprocessing to ensure that the length along each dimension will be consistent.

First, reindex the data frame with the full cartesian product of all dimensions. `NaN` values will be inserted as needed. This operation can be both slow and consume a lot of memory, depending on the number of dimensions and on the size of the data frame.

```
levels = map(tuple, frame.index.levels)
index = list(product(*levels))
frame = frame.reindex(index)
print(frame)
```

which outputs

```
       value
0 0 0      0
    1      1
  1 0      2
    1      3
1 0 0      4
    1    NaN
  1 0      6
    1      7
```

Now, `reshape()` will work as intended.

```
shape = map(len, frame.index.levels)
print(frame.values.reshape(shape))
```

which outputs

```
[[[  0.   1.]
  [  2.   3.]]

 [[  4.  nan]
  [  6.   7.]]]
```

The (rather ugly) one-liner is

```
frame.reindex(list(product(*map(tuple, frame.index.levels)))).values\
     .reshape(map(len, frame.index.levels))
```

Comment: works nicely! there's a minor typo: `frame.reindex(levels)`  should be `frame.reindex(index)`.

Comment: For us noobies; don't forget that in python3 you'll need to turn the result of 'map' into a list before any of this will work. ie. `shape = list(map(len, frame.index.levels))`

Comment: Getting the shape is more straight forward: `frame.index.levshape`. Neither this nor the given solution seem to work with non-unique indices.

Comment: Doing `df.index.labels` I get `AttributeError: 'MultiIndex' object has no attribute 'labels'`. What's up with that?

Comment: @CrabMan Very late response, but `MultiIndex.labels` has been deprecated in favor of `MultiIndex.codes` - using the latter should fix the error. (https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/whatsnew/v0.24.0.html#deprecations)

Comment: `arr[frame.index.codes]` gives a deprecation warning from Numpy 1.15 and stops working in Numpy 1.23 (https://numpy.org/doc/stable/release/1.23.0-notes.html). `arr[tuple(frame.index.codes)]` does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done quite nicely using the Python xarray package which can be found here: http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/. It has great integration with Pandas and is quite intuitive once you get to grips with it.

If you have a multiindex series you can call the built-in method multiindex_series.to_xarray() (https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_xarray.html). This will generate a DataArray object, which is essentially a name-indexed numpy array, using the index values and names as coordinates. Following this you can call .values on the DataArray object to get the underlying numpy array.

If you need your tensor to conform to a set of keys in a specific order, you can also call .reindex(index_name = index_values_in_order) (http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.reindex.html) on the DataArray. This can be extremely useful and makes working with the newly generated tensor much easier!