# Convert a Pandas DataFrame to a multidimensional ndarray

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a DataFrame with columns for the x, y, z coordinates and the value at this position and I want to convert this to a 3-dimensional ndarray.

To make things more complicated, not all values exist in the DataFrame (these can just be replaced by NaN in the ndarray).

Just a simple example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2], 
                   'y': [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2],
                   'z': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
                   'value': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]})
```

Should result in the ndarray:

```
array([[[  1.,   2.,  nan],
        [  3.,  nan,   4.]],

       [[  5.,   6.,   7.],
        [  8.,   9.,  nan]]])
```

For two dimensions, this is easy:

```
array = df.pivot_table(index="y", columns="x", values="value").as_matrix()
```

However, this method can not be applied to three or more dimensions.

Could you give me some suggestions?

Bonus points if this also works for more than three dimensions, handles multiple defined values (by taking the average) and ensures that all x, y, z coordinates are consecutive (by inserting row/columns of NaN when a coordinate is missing).

**EDIT:** Some more explanations:

I read data from a CSV file which has the columns for x, y, z coordinates, optionally the frequency and the measurement value at this point and frequency. Then I round the coordinates to a specified precision (e.g. 0.1m) and want to get an ndarray which contains the averaged measurement values at each (rounded) coordinates. The indizes of the values do not need to coincide with the location. However they need to be in the correct order.

**EDIT:** I just ran a quick performance test:

The solution of jakevdp takes 1.598s, Divikars solution takes 7.405s, JohnE's solution takes 7.867s and Wens solution takes 6.286s to complete.

Comment: your 2 dimensions trick doesn't do what you said in question. i.e. array is not an ndarray. it is still an DataFrame.

Comment: @stucash Sorry, I changed it to return an ndarray instead

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transform Pandas DataFrame with n-level hierarchical index into n-D Numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35047882/transform-pandas-dataframe-with-n-level-hierarchical-index-into-n-d-numpy-array)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use a `groupby` followed by the approach from [Transform Pandas DataFrame with n-level hierarchical index into n-D Numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35047882/transform-pandas-dataframe-with-n-level-hierarchical-index-into-n-d-numpy-array):

```
grouped = df.groupby(['z', 'y', 'x'])['value'].mean()

# create an empty array of NaN of the right dimensions
shape = tuple(map(len, grouped.index.levels))
arr = np.full(shape, np.nan)

# fill it using Numpy's advanced indexing
arr[grouped.index.labels] = grouped.values.flat

print(arr)
# [[[  1.   2.  nan]
#   [  3.  nan   4.]]
# 
#  [[  5.   6.   7.]
#   [  8.   9.  nan]]]
```

Comment: As an added bonus you even get the "axis labels" in `grouped.index.levels`.

Comment: I'm getting AttributeError: 'MultiIndex' object has no attribute 'labels'.

Comment: ```# fill it using Numpy's advanced indexing
arr[grouped.index.labels] = grouped.values.flat``` should be changed to ```arr[tuple(grouped.index.codes)] = grouped.values.flat``` for this approach to work in pandas 1.4.2

Comment: how is it possible to do this to conserve the shape (i.e., dimensions), but keep the original values of "value" column and not aggregate it via ".mean()"?

Answer (score 2):

Here's one NumPy approach -

```
def dataframe_to_array_averaged(df):
    arr = df[['z','y','x']].values
    arr -= arr.min(0)
    out_shp = arr.max(0)+1

    L = np.prod(out_shp)

    val = df['value'].values
    ids = np.ravel_multi_index(arr.T, out_shp)

    avgs = np.bincount(ids, val, minlength=L)/np.bincount(ids, minlength=L)
    return avgs.reshape(out_shp)
```

Note that that this shows a warning because for places with no x,y,z triplets would have zero counts and hence the average values would be `0/0` = `NaN`, but since that's the expected output for those places, you can ignore the warning there. To avoid this warning, we can employ indexing, as discussed in the second method (Alternative method).

Sample run -

```
In [106]: df
Out[106]: 
   value  x  y  z
0      1  1  1  1  # <=== this is repeated
1      2  2  1  1
2      3  1  2  1
3      4  3  2  1
4      5  1  1  2
5      6  2  1  2
6      7  3  1  2
7      8  1  2  2
8      9  2  2  2
9      4  1  1  1  # <=== this is repeated

In [107]: dataframe_to_array_averaged(df)
__main__:42: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in divide
Out[107]: 
array([[[ 2.5,  2. ,  nan],
        [ 3. ,  nan,  4. ]],

       [[ 5. ,  6. ,  7. ],
        [ 8. ,  9. ,  nan]]])
```

**Alternative method**

To avoid warning, an alternative way would be like so -

```
out = np.full(out_shp,  np.nan)
sums = np.bincount(ids, val)
unq_ids, count = np.unique(ids, return_counts=1)
out.flat[:unq_ids[-1]] = sums
out.flat[unq_ids] /= count
```

Comment: Unfortunately this fails with the error "TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer" if the inputs are not integers. After adding ".astype(int), the error message is "TypeError: Iterator operand 0 dtype could not be cast from dtype('float64') to dtype('int64') according to the rule 'same_kind'".

Comment: @DanielSch. You need the indices as integer, which aren't it seems going by the error . So, do: `arr = df[['z','y','x']].values.astype(int)`.

Comment: Sorry I forgot the mentions this: The values in my application are floats, so converting them to integers is not an option :-/

Comment: @DanielSch. What do you mean by its not an option? What's the hurdle with converting? It would extract and convert only the X, Y, Z columns only, not the Value col. The input dataframe stays the same.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the mention, that my coordinates are also float values, my bad :-/

Comment: @DanielSch. Well if the indices are floats, how can we assign into an array? `array[1.2, 2.1, 3.2]`? That would be invalid anyway.

Comment: @Divikar Sorry, I added some more explanations to the question, I hope this clears things up. My example may have been a little misleading :-/

Comment: @DanielSch. Okay, so you mentioned - `want to get an ndarray which contains the averaged measurement values at each (rounded) coordinates`. So, basically you are rounding. You should have mentioned that earlier. Thus, simply do : `arr = np.round(df[['z','y','x']].values).astype(int)`.

Comment: @Divikar I think I have to do `arr = np.round(df[['z','y','x']].values / resolution).astype(int)`, then it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to use the `xarray` package:

```
import pandas as pd
import xarray as xr
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2], 
                   'y': [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2],
                   'z': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
                   'value': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]})
df = pd.pivot_table(df, values='value', index=['x', 'y', 'z'])
xrTensor = xr.DataArray(df).unstack("dim_0")
array = xrTensor.values[0].T
print(array)
```

Output:

```
array([[[ 1.,  2., nan],
        [ 3., nan,  4.]],

       [[ 5.,  6.,  7.],
        [ 8.,  9., nan]]])
```

Note that the `xrTensor` object is very handy since xarray's `DataArray`s contain the labels so you may just go on with that object rather pulling out the `ndarray`:

```
print(xrTensor)
```

Output:

```
<xarray.DataArray (dim_1: 1, x: 3, y: 2, z: 2)>
array([[[[ 1.,  5.],
         [ 3.,  8.]],

        [[ 2.,  6.],
         [nan,  9.]],

        [[nan,  7.],
         [ 4., nan]]]])
Coordinates:
  * dim_1    (dim_1) object 'value'
  * x        (x) int64 1 2 3
  * y        (y) int64 1 2
  * z        (z) int64 1 2
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about this package yet :-)

Answer (score 0):

We can using `stack`

```
np.reshape(df.groupby(['z', 'y', 'x'])['value'].mean().unstack([1,2]).stack([0,1],dropna=False).values,(2,2,3))


Out[451]: 
array([[[  1.,   2.,  nan],
        [  3.,  nan,   4.]],
       [[  5.,   6.,   7.],
        [  8.,   9.,  nan]]])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately this fails for 4 dimensions, because the order of the elements gets mixed up (I suspect, that the parameters to stack and unstack have to be changed)

Comment: @DanielSch. yes you need to change it